# Vuetifty: Can't seem to change Datatables fonts at all

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to change datatable font size and font family in my component.  After looking up answers here, I tried applying it via:

```
table.v-table tbody td {
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

I also tried adding an ID to my `v-data-table` to add specificity in my CSS and that still didn't apply it.

Lastly, I tried to right click in chrome and do 'copy selector' and use that very specific selector to no avail

Comment: have you tried inline styling?

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine inline would work but I am trying to avoid that if at all possible